# Using R package logger with data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, logging

I'm using [logger](https://github.com/daroczig/logger) for logging. Now I want to log the contents of a `data.frame`, currently, this yields something like this:

```
> logger::log_formatter(logger::formatter_paste)
> logger::log_info(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6))
INFO [2019-05-03 14:36:29] 1:3
INFO [2019-05-03 14:36:29] 4:6
```

This is not what I want, is it possible to get something like below

```
INFO [2019-05-03 14:36:29]   a b
INFO [2019-05-03 14:36:29] 1 1 4
INFO [2019-05-03 14:36:29] 2 2 5
INFO [2019-05-03 14:36:29] 3 3 6
```

as `print()` would give?

Comment: I get an error when running `logger::log_info(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6))` on R 3.5.2

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the issue as Cett mentioned.  getting error

Comment: @Cettt I've added a formatter so it doesn't error any more. Of course, I like it to work with any formatter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default formatter in `logger` is `glue` (or `sprintf` if the `glue` package is not installed), which yields an error on passing data frames:

```
glue::glue(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6))
#> Error: All unnamed arguments must be length 1

sprintf(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6))
#> Error in sprintf(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)) : 
#>   'fmt' is not a character vector
```

So if you want `logger` to work with data frames, you need a custom formatter, eg

```
formatter_data_frame <- function(df, ...) {
    pander::pander_return(df, style = 'simple')
}

library(logger)
log_formatter(formatter_data_frame)
log_info(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6))
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:33:47] 
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:33:47]  a   b 
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:33:47] --- ---
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:33:47]  1   4 
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:33:47]  2   5 
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:33:47]  3   6 
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:33:47]
```

Or with what you tried to achieve with calling `paste` on each line:

```
formatter_data_frame <- function(df, ...) {
    apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = ' ')
}

log_formatter(formatter_data_frame)
log_info(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6))
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:35:03] 1 4
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:35:03] 2 5
#> INFO [2019-05-04 11:35:03] 3 6
```

Of course, you could tweak this further, eg to do this for a `data.frame` and fall back to `glue` on other objects etc

Another approach is using an eval helper:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
log_eval(df)
#> TRACE [2019-05-04 11:37:12] 'df' => 'structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))'
```

If you think there's something missing from the package that would be useful, please open a ticket in the GitHub repo at https://github.com/daroczig/logger

Comment: Thanks for the information, very helpful. Ideally, the formatter doesn't have to be changed and it just accepts data.frames. I'm trying to figure out whether that is easily done using S3 methods somehow.

Comment: I've created a [PR](https://github.com/daroczig/logger/pull/22) with an idea for S3 methods based approach.